# ActionListener implementation in Java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

Could you please help me use the ActionListener correclty in my code? The code compiles and the GUI is displayed correctly, but no button works!! If you want to test the code, note that you need to put the image in the same folder as the project file created and change the line "ImageIcon myImageIcon = new ImageIcon("rodeo.jpg");" according to the name of your photo.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageApplication extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
public Image myImage;
public JLabel myImageLabel;
public ImageIcon myImageIcon;
public JFrame frame;
public JTextField txtWidth, txtHeight;
public int origWidth, origHeight;


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int origWidth, origHeight;
    ImageApplication ia = new ImageApplication();
    ia.setVisible(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    ImageIcon myImageIcon = new ImageIcon("rodeo.jpg");
    JLabel myImageLabel = new JLabel(myImageIcon, JLabel.CENTER);
    Image myImage = myImageIcon.getImage();


    origWidth = myImageIcon.getIconWidth();
    origHeight = myImageIcon.getIconHeight();

    JMenuBar myMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu myMenu = new JMenu("Options");
    JMenuItem myMenuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Double");
    JMenuItem myMenuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Reset");
    myMenu.add(myMenuItem1);
    myMenu.add(myMenuItem2);
    myMenuBar.add(myMenu);
    ia.setJMenuBar(myMenuBar);

    JButton bAL = new JButton("Align Left");
    JButton bAC = new JButton("Align Center");
    JButton bAR = new JButton("Align Right");
    JButton bResize = new JButton ("Resize");
    bAL.setFocusPainted(false);
    bAC.setFocusPainted(false);
    bAR.setFocusPainted(false);
    bResize.setFocusPainted(false);

    JLabel lWidth = new JLabel("Width:");
    JLabel lHeight = new JLabel("Height:");
    JTextField txtWidth = new JTextField(Integer.toString(origWidth));
    JTextField txtHeight = new JTextField(Integer.toString(origHeight));

    JPanel GRID = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1f;
    c.weighty = 0f;

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    GRID.add(bAL, c);
    c.gridx++;
    GRID.add(bAC, c);
    c.gridx++;
    GRID.add(bAR, c);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    GRID.add(myImageLabel, c);
    c.gridwidth = 1;

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    GRID.add(lWidth, c);
    c.gridx++;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    GRID.add(txtWidth, c);
    c.gridwidth = 1;

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    GRID.add(lHeight, c);
    c.gridx++;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    GRID.add(txtHeight, c);
    c.gridwidth = 1;

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 4;
    GRID.add(bResize, c);

    ia.add(GRID, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    ia.setSize(origWidth + 150, origHeight + 150);

    myMenuItem1.addActionListener(ia);
    myMenuItem1.setActionCommand("double");
    myMenuItem2.addActionListener(ia);
    myMenuItem2.setActionCommand("reset");
    bAL.addActionListener(ia);
    bAL.setActionCommand("left");
    bAC.addActionListener(ia);
    bAC.setActionCommand("center");
    bAR.addActionListener(ia);
    bAR.setActionCommand("right");
    bResize.addActionListener(ia);
    bResize.setActionCommand("resize");
}



private void ResizeImage(int Width, int Height)
{
    myImage = myImage.getScaledInstance(Width, Height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    myImageIcon.setImage(myImage);
    myImageLabel.setIcon(myImageIcon);

    txtWidth.setText(Integer.toString(Width));
    txtHeight.setText(Integer.toString(Height));

    setSize(Width + 150, Height + 150);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String command = e.getActionCommand();

    if(command == "left") myImageLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    else if(command == "center") myImageLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    else if(command == "right") myImageLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
    else if(command == "resize") ResizeImage(Integer.parseInt(txtWidth.getText()),       
    Integer.parseInt(txtHeight.getText()));
    else if(command == "double") ResizeImage(myImageIcon.getIconWidth() * 2,  
    myImageIcon.getIconHeight() * 2);
    else if(command == "reset") ResizeImage(origWidth, origHeight);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `String#equals` to compare `String` content. You are using the `==` operator which compares Object references.

However, as the buttons have differing functionality, better for each to have an individual `ActionListener`. This can be done using an anonymous `ActionListener` instance.

Side issue: The class member variable `myImageLabel` is not being assigned. Rather another variable 
with the same name is initialized in the `static` main method. You need to move all the components instantiated in the main method into an instance method and also remove the JLabel local class declaration.

*After moving code:*

```
JLabel myImageLabel = new JLabel(myImageIcon, JLabel.CENTER);
```

should be

```
myImageLabel = new JLabel(myImageIcon, JLabel.CENTER);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but this didn't solve the problem. When pushing a button I get this "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ImageApplication.actionPerformed(ImageApplication.java:129)
"

Comment: check the lines "myMenuItem1.addActionListener(ia);" could ia be a problem there? I couldn't use "this" at that point so I used the object of the class application...

Comment: You need to move all the components instantiated in the `main` method into an instance method and _also_ remove the `JLabel` local class declaration.

Comment: It is better as you need to instantiate class member or instance variables. The best place to do this is in an instance method. Many Swing apps have an `initComponents` instance method for e.g.

Comment: Ok but then how is the instance method going to be invoked? If I have only the ia object creation and the setvisible method in static main??

Comment: it's going to be by the set visible ... Thanks a lot for the help :) have a nice day/night!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:
What it does: it adds to the button itself, when clicked an method to be performed:

```
buttonName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //do what ever
            }
        });
        //set bunds for the button itself, if not done otherwise, but for your layout.
```

Comment: ? What's with the `setBounds` ? I didn't see that anywhere in the OP's code?  Given the fact that they don't know about `String` comparisons I doubt it's a good idea to start showing them this - IMHO

Answer (score 1):

These instance variables:

```
public JTextField txtWidth, txtHeight;
```

are never initialized but are referred to in your listener code.  You have local variables of the same name that you're instantiating. Change this:

```
JTextField txtWidth = new JTextField(Integer.toString(origWidth));
JTextField txtHeight = new JTextField(Integer.toString(origHeight));
```

to this:

```
txtWidth = new JTextField(Integer.toString(origWidth));
txtHeight = new JTextField(Integer.toString(origHeight));
```

and similarly for your other instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get Image

ImageIcon myImageIcon = new ImageIcon("rodeo.jpg").getImage();